# What is the best way to check if discount id is valid or not in Braintree Payment Integration with Laravel

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, braintree, laravel-5.8, laravel-cashier

I am trying to integrate Braintree Payment Gateway with Laravel, I am using Laravel Cashier for subscription in my system.

Now I am planning to give a discount to my customers, I am not able to find the way to check if the Discount id is valid or not in Braintree Control Panel.

Is there any one with a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

I would recommend storing your created discount IDs within a database that you can reference when creating subscriptions. Additionally, you can use the [`Discounts.all()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/discount/all) API call, which will return a collection of all discount objects. From there you can iterate through the result to check the validity of the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works for me. But I need one more layer in this to check validity of discount ID for particular Plan. Is it available in Braintree or i dont know how to achieve this ?

Comment: You can use [Plan.all()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/plan/all) to check all plans. The `discounts` object will contain the discounts associated with the subscription. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).